# How does the node element function not run automatically when creating a table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, servlets

I am creating a series of tables based on a javascript array and have encountered a major problem.

This is my implementation step, I hit the "**show top gundam**" button to create the table using the "**createTable**" function. Then I will hit "**remove**" button to delete the table that I do not like.

The prolem is it completely started the function name "**removeDiv**" of "**remove**" button automatically when I pressed the "**show top gundam**" button to create a table. My idea is that every time I press the remove button it will be based on the parameter "id" of each div to delete it.

Is there any way to make it not run automatically and only run when I click the remove button?

```
  <body onload="convertXmlToJavaScriptObject()">
    <div style="margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 20px">
        <form action="DispatcherController">
            <input name="btAction" value="Crawl data" type="submit" class="btn-dark" id="crawl" onclick="showLoader()" />
            <input name="btAction" value="Clear all record" type="submit" class="btn-dark" onclick="setZero()" />
            <input name="btAction" value="Show Top Gundam" class="btn-dark" onclick="creatTable()"/>
            <div class="loader" style="margin-top: 10px;display: none" id="loader"></div>
        </form>
        <button class="btn-dark" onclick="">Create table</button>

        <!--Nếu như xóa thành công thì hiện chữ-->
        <c:if test="${requestScope.DELETE>0 or requestScope.DELETE==0}">
            <font style="color: blue" id="del"><p><h5>Xóa thành công</h5></p></font>
            </c:if>
    <!--<input type="submit" value="Click me" class="btn-dark" id="crawl" onclick="showLoader()"/>-->

    <c:set var="gundam" value="${requestScope.FULLLIST}" />


    <!--Mới mở trang lên thì nó sẽ show có tổng cộng có bao nhiêu record-->

    <!--Đây là số record sau khi crawl xong-->
    <c:set var="crawlrecord" value="${requestScope.COUNT}"/>

    <!--Đây là số rerord còn ở trong DB-->
    <c:set var="couting" value="${applicationScope['COUNTRECORD']}"/>

    <div style="margin-top: 20px">
        Tổng số record cào về <p id="record" style="font-weight: bold">${crawlrecord}</p>

    </div> 
    <div><p style="text-align: center">----------------Gundam-------------------</p></div>

    <c:forEach items="${applicationScope.TESTTOP}" var="item">
        <!--                        <div style="width: 600px">
                                    <table style="margin-bottom: 10px;width: 100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width: 30%"><img src="${item.avatar}" width="150px"></th>
                                            <th style="width: 70%">
                                                <p>${item.name}<br/>${item.price}<br/>${item.type}</p>
                                                <p><button>Add</button><button style="margin-left: 10px">Remove</button></p>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>-->
    </c:forEach>




    <script>
        var array = [];//Tạo 1 array để lưu những gundam object đc chuyển từ hàm convertXmlToJavaScriptObject, thuận tiện cho việc thêm, xóa, sửa

        //        Hàm này có tổng cộng chức năng như sau
        //        1 là nó sẽ show cái loader khi đang crawl
        //        2 là nó sẽ tắt cái chữ delete
        //        3 là nó show số record sau khi crawl xong
        function showLoader() {
            var deleted = document.getElementById("del");
            var x = document.getElementById('loader');
            //Nếu như có danh sách rồi thì tắt cái loader và xóa đi cái chữ "xóa thành công rồi nếu nó có đang hiện"
            //khi nhấn vào nút crawl thì cái loader sẽ hiện
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
        <c:set var="couting" value="${requestScope.COUNT}"/>
                document.getElementById("record").innerHTML = "${couting}";
            }
        }
        ;
        //Xóa hết record thì hiện là zero
        function setZero() {
            document.getElementById("record").innerHTML = "0";
            var show = document.getElementById("del");
            if (show.style.display === "none") {
                show.style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        /*
         * Hàm này dùng để convert xml thành javascript object
         * Đã thành công

         * @returns {undefined}             */
        function convertXmlToJavaScriptObject() {

            //Chuyển String thành DOM
            var xmlString = '${applicationScope.TOP}';
            var xmlDOc;

            var paser = new DOMParser();
            var xml = paser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");


            var path = "/items/item";
            var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
            var result = nodes.iterateNext();//Duyệt từng node đã có đc từ xpath
            while (result) {
                var item = {
                    id: "",
                    name: "",
                    price: "",
                    avatar: "",
                    link: "",
                    type: "",
                    firstDateAppearance: "",
                    numberOfTimeClicked: ""
                };
                item.name = result.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;//Vì bây h current node là item nên chỉ có duy nhất 1 name node, ta viết thế này sẽ dễ lấy
                item.id = result.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                item.price = result.getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                item.avatar = result.getElementsByTagName("avatar")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                item.link = result.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                item.firstDateAppearance = result.getElementsByTagName("firstDateAppearance")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                console.log(item.firstDateAppearance);
                item.numberOfTimeClicked = result.getElementsByTagName("numberOfTimeClicked")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                array.push(item);

                //Đi tới node tiếp theo sau khi duyệt ở node hiện tại
                //Giống như thầy Khánh nói, khi duyệt node thì luôn phải bắt đầu ở ndoe mới 
                result = nodes.iterateNext();
            }
            console.log(array.length);
            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                console.log(array[i].name);
            }
        }



        /**
         * functin này sẽ tạo ra 1 cái table
         */
        function creatTable() {
            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                //tạo 1 object chứa function


                var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.setAttribute('id', array[i].id);
                div.style.width = "600px";

                //tạo cái table
                var table = document.createElement('table');
                table.style.marginBottom = "10px";
                table.style.width = "100%";
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');


                var firstTh = document.createElement("th");
                firstTh.style.width = "30%";
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.setAttribute('width', '150px');
                img.setAttribute('src', array[i].avatar);
                firstTh.appendChild(img);


                //Cái th thứ 2
                var secontTh = document.createElement('th');
                secontTh.style.width = "70%";

                var pFirst = document.createElement('p');
                pFirst.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i].name));//Lấy name
                var br = document.createElement('br');
                pFirst.appendChild(br);

                pFirst.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i].price));//lấy giá
                var br = document.createElement('br');
                pFirst.appendChild(br);

                pFirst.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i].type));//lấy type

                //node p thứ 2
                var pSecond = document.createElement('p');
                var add = document.createElement('button');
                add.setAttribute('class', 'btn-success');
                add.innerHTML = "Add";

                var remove = document.createElement('button');
                remove.innerHTML = "Remove";
                remove.setAttribute('class', 'btn-danger');
                var idNode = array[i].id;
                remove.onclick = function () {
                    removeDiv(idNode)
                };
                remove.style.marginLeft = "10px";

                //tạo ra node id
                var infoId = document.createElement("idnode");
                infoId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i].id));
                infoId.style.display = "none";
                pSecond.appendChild(add);
                pSecond.appendChild(remove);

                //add 2 cái p vào cái th thứ 2
                secontTh.appendChild(pFirst);
                secontTh.appendChild(pSecond);

                tr.appendChild(firstTh);
                tr.appendChild(secontTh);
                table.appendChild(tr);
                div.appendChild(table);
                div.appendChild(infoId);
                body.appendChild(div);
            }

        }

        function tableCreate() {
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            var tbl = document.createElement('table');
            tbl.style.width = '100%';
            tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
            var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    if (i == 2 && j == 1) {
                        break
                    } else {
                        var td = document.createElement('td');
                        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u0020'))
                        i == 1 && j == 1 ? td.setAttribute('rowSpan', '2') : null;
                        tr.appendChild(td)
                    }
                }
                tbdy.appendChild(tr);
            }
            tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
            body.appendChild(tbl)
        }




        /**
         * Hàm này dùng để test gửi xmlHttpRequest về để nhận data mà ko cần load trang
         * Đã thành công
         * @returns {undefined}
         */
        function testing() {
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "GetTheTopIDServlet?name=sam";
            var xmlDom;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                    xmlDom = xmlHttp.responseXML;//responseXML là dữ liệu thuộc kiểu XML
                    if (xmlDom != null) {
                        var x = xmlDom.getElementsByTagName("name");
                        console.log(x.length)
                        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                            console.log("Day la value= " + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("null bỏ mẹ rùi");
                    }

                }
            };
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);//Bắt đầu gửi request đi
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        /**
         * Hàm này sẽ remove table mà ta chọn dựa trên id
         * @param {type} id
         * @returns {undefined}
         */
        function removeDiv() {
            console.log("hehe");
        }
    </script>
```

Update prolem

> ```
>  var idNode = array[i].id;
>     remove.onclick = function () {
>      removeDiv(idNode)
>   };
> ```

I was able to catch the event separately but a new problem is that instead of getting the correct id of each table, it always chooses the last id generated from the object array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove.onclick` is being set to the *return value* of executing `removeDiv` (the '()' following `removeDiv`), which is likely undefined. So when the button is clicked, javascript tries to *execute* undefined which just doesn't make sense.

Instead, it should be set to the function itself... i.e.

```js
    remove.onclick = removeDiv
```

You can also wrap `removeDiv` in an anonymous function if you need to pass it arguments.

```js
    remove.onclick = function() {
        removeDiv(idNode)
    }
    // OR using ES6 arrow function syntax
    remove.onclick = () => removeDiv(idNode);
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Your solution work right. But when I add more parameter like this "removeDiv(idNode)". It turn auto run automatically again. What should i do

Comment: You can wrap it in an anonymous function. The key is to not execute the fucntion your setting onClick to.

Comment: Once again it work, but i have new bug. The given id is always the last id of the last "div". Here is the code I rewrote when you instructed:

 var idNode = array [i] .id;
 remove.onclick = function () {
                        removeDiv (idNode)
                    };

Comment: Hmm Can you update the code in your question to the updated code so I can see it in full context?